# How do I access a color programmatically in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I tired using ContextCompact but I'm having 'unresolved reference'

```
 val changeColour = ContextCompat.getColor(closestView.context, R.color.white.color
)
```

Comment: it should just be `R.color.white`, not `R.color.white.color`

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected it. Although the 'closetView' is giving another error: Unresolved reference: closestView